# Simplify sympy integral expressions

Tags: python, sympy, simplify, symbolic-integration

With

```
x, a, b, c = symbols ('x a b c')
f = Function ('f') (x)
```

is there a way to simplify

```
integrate (f, (x, a, b)) + integrate (f, (x, b, a))
```

and

```
integrate (f, (x, a, c)) + integrate (f, (x, c, b)) - integrate (f, (x, a, b))
```

to zero?

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Conventions

Comment: I don't think there's a ready made function for this in sympy but you could make your own. The idea would be to find linear combinations of integrals and look for cycles connecting the limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first case can be handled by using a traversal that puts the limits in canonical order:

```
def iss(i):
   if isinstance(i, Integral):
     s = 1
     lim = list(i.limits)
     for j, xab in enumerate(lim):
         if len(xab) == 3:
             x, a, b = xab
             if [a,b]!=list(ordered([a,b])):
                 lim[j] = (x, b, a)
                 s *= -1
     return i.func(i.function, lim).simplify()*s
   return i

>>> eq = integrate (f, (x, a, b)) + integrate (f, (x, b, a))
>>> bottom_up(eq, iss)
0
```

For the second case there are lots of possible expressions to deal with. But to deal with the type you have shown perhaps the following will work:

```
def collapse_integrals(a):
    from collections import defaultdict
    if not a.is_Add: return a
    i, d = a.as_independent(Integral)
    if not d.is_Add:
        return a
    if i:
        return i + collapse_integrals(d)
    igls = defaultdict(list)
    other = []
    for ai in a.args:
        c, i = ai.as_independent(Integral, as_Add=False)
        if abs(c) != 1:
            other.append(ai)
            continue
        if not isinstance(i,Integral) or not (len(i.limits) == 1 and len(i.limits[0])==3):
            other.append(ai)
        else:
            igls[(c, i.function)].append(i.limits[0][1:])
    for k in igls:
        if len(igls[k]) > 1:
            n = len(igls[k])
            lims = igls[k]
            cond = []
            nul = (None, None)
            for i in range(n):
                if lims[i] == nul:continue
                for j in range(i + 1, n):
                    if lims[i][0] == lims[j][1]:
                        cond.append((lims[j][0],lims[i][1]))
                    elif lims[i][1] == lims[j][0]:
                        cond.append((lims[i][0],lims[j][1]))
                    else:
                        continue
                    lims[i] = lims[j] = nul
            if cond:
                igls[k] = cond + [i for i in lims if i != nul]
        c, f = k
        other.extend([c*Integral(f, l) for l in igls[k]])
    return Add(*other)

>>> eq = integrate (f, (x, a, c)) + integrate (f, (x, c, b)) - integrate (f, (x, a, b))
collapse_integrals(bottom_up(eq,iss))
0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for my chance to learn that sympy offers different traversals. From your own experience of sympy development, would you expect that sympy itself will be able to simplify those integral expressions automatically in the near future? The reason for my question is that I teach mathematics in mechanical engineering with the symbolic toolbox of Matlab and I am trying to figure out whether I could use Python instead of Matlab.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is too specific of a simplification, but it would be worth raising it as an issue [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues).

Comment: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/23282

Comment: Oops: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/23281 How do we proceed?

Comment: I merged my additional comments to your issue. No problem. Thanks for opening the issue.